# How to call and get result of void function?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**Description:** 
On my homepage, each user enters their nickname and click on button to start game. Then each player must answer a multiple choice and finally the score is displayed.

**Problems**
When i call 'initQuestion()', I can't get the value of result and I have some errors like "This expression has type 'void' and can't be used." or "The method drive was called on null"

**Code**
My HomePage call Game() function:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:trivia/src/screens/questionpage.dart';

class Game extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<String> _playerNameList;
  final String gameMode; // Easy, Normal, Hard defined on HomePage
  Game(this.gameMode, this._playerNameList);


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //variables
    int round = 3;
    int playerNumber = _playerNameList.length;
    Map<String, int> score; //List to store score like {'PlayerName1': '0', 'PlayerName2": '0', ...};

    //Function
    for (int i = 0; i < round; i++) { //for each round
      for (int j = 0; j < playerNumber; j++) { //for each player

        int result = initQuestion(context, gameMode, _playerNameList[j]); // Run "Question game"
        score[_playerNameList[j]] = score[_playerNameList[j]]+result; // Get result (1 if answer correct; 0 if answer invalid) and store score

      }
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Game end'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('The winner is ...'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

initQuestion(context, gameMode, playerName) async {

    //Question
    String question = "In which continent is France located?";
    List<String> _choice = <String>["Europe","Asia","Africa"];
    String answer = "Europe";

  final result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => QuestionPage(playerName: playerName, answer: answer, choice: _choice, question: question)),
  );
  //Get result (0 or 1)
  return result; //--> Edited thx Selim Kundakçıoğlu

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`void` means function doesn't return anything. So instead of using `void` you can change your return type to `int` and instead of `print(result);` you can do `return result;`

Comment: thx i edited my code, i have other error message "NoSuchMethodError: The method 'drive' was called on null'. I don't know where it could come from

Comment: Do you have a method called drive?

Comment: I have not "drive" method. The root error message in my console is : type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'int'. I think the problem come from "score" list